# How to convert older Pandas indexing code to Pandas 2.0.2?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to convert some code in a book that uses Pandas 1.x to current Pandas, but the method level within the function count seems to have been deprecated.

Here is the code:

```
MovieLens.set_index(["title", "rating"]).count(level="rating")["user_id"]
IndUsers = MovieLens.set_index(["movie_id", "user_id"]).count(level="user_id")["title"]
print("Average movie reviews per user: ", IndUsers.mean())

IndMovies = MovieLens.set_index(["user_id", "title"]).count(level="title")["movie_id"]
print("\nNumber of Reviews Per Movie\n")
print(IndMovies)
```

The data structure (MovieLens) and output is as follows:

```
     user_id  movie_id  rating  timestamp gender  age  occupation    zip  \
```

0              1      1193       5  978300760      F    1          10  48067
1              2      1193       5  978298413      M   56          16  70072
2             12      1193       4  978220179      M   25          12  32793
3             15      1193       4  978199279      M   25           7  22903
4             17      1193       5  978158471      M   50           1  95350
...          ...       ...     ...        ...    ...  ...         ...    ...
1000204     5949      2198       5  958846401      M   18          17  47901
1000205     5675      2703       3  976029116      M   35          14  30030
1000206     5780      2845       1  958153068      M   18          17  92886
1000207     5851      3607       5  957756608      F   18          20  55410
1000208     5938      2909       4  957273353      M   25           1  35401

```
                                           title                genres
```

0             One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest (1975)                 Drama
1             One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest (1975)                 Drama
2             One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest (1975)                 Drama
3             One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest (1975)                 Drama
4             One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest (1975)                 Drama
...                                              ...                   ...
1000204                           Modulations (1998)           Documentary
1000205                        Broken Vessels (1998)                 Drama
1000206                            White Boys (1999)                 Drama
1000207                     One Little Indian (1973)  Comedy|Drama|Western
1000208  Five Wives, Three Secretaries and Me (1998)           Documentary

[1000209 rows x 10 columns]

---

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[16], line 29
26 MovieLens = pd.merge(pd.merge(ratings, users), movies)
28 print(MovieLens)
---> 29 MovieLens.set_index(["title", "rating"]).count(level="rating")["user_id"]
30 IndUsers = MovieLens.set_index(["movie_id", "user_id"]).count(level="user_id")["title"]
31 #MovieLens.set_index(["title", "rating"]).count()["user_id"]
32 #IndUsers = MovieLens.set_index(["movie_id", "user_id"]).count()["title"]

TypeError: DataFrame.count() got an unexpected keyword argument 'level'

Expected Output (I am typing this out by hand since copy-paste is blocked by the book)
Average Movie Reviews per User: 165.597...

Number of Reviews per Movie

title
$1,000,000 Duck (1971) 37
[...additional movies]
eXistenZ (1999) 410

I don't see a simple method within Pandas 2.0.2 to replace this.

-> Code generates an error
-> Code without level doesn't differentiate between users (i.e. it ignores user_id, assumes all users were the same)
-> Other count options in Pandas 2.0.2 don't provide the desired function

Comment: As presented, your question doesn't make any sense.  Please edit your question to show a validly formatted minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```py
MovieLens.set_index(["title", "rating"]).groupby('rating' ["user_id"].count()

IndUsers = MovieLens.set_index(
         ["movie_id", "user_id"]). groupby('user_id')["title"].count()

print("Average movie reviews per user: ", IndUsers.mean())

IndMovies = MovieLens.set_index(
 ["user_id", "title"]).groupby('title')["movie_id"].count()

print("\nNumber of Reviews Per Movie\n")
print(IndMovies)
```